# Custom pages for auth grant and password reset

Tags: keycloak

I have my frontend written in React and for auth I use keycloak hosted by me by some 3rd party org. The problem I have is that keycloak pages design is completely different from my UI. I know it's possible to customize the CSS from keycloak admin console, but I would rather prefer to have custom pages for every operation written in React on my side.

**1. Login**

it's easy, i just need to expose an endpoint in my backend which will take login and password from React form and obtain token from keycloak by calling token endpoint **POST {host}/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token** with password grant as method

**2. Registration**

Here it's similar, I just react page with form where I collect username and email and password and call my backend which will call `POST {host}/admin/realms/{realmName}/users`

**3. Password reset**

This one I don't know how to do. On my endpoint I can add lin "reset password", then when user clicks it I will call my backend, my backend will call keycloak `PUT /auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email` with `"UPDATE_PASSWORD"` then user receives a magic link to their email and when they click it they will go to keycloak page, which is the problem. Is it possible to make it in a way that the user goes to my React page to enter a new password after clicking the magic link from email?

**4. Auth grant****

This is about a case when some 3rd party client want authorization from my user and sends the user to consent screen where the user needs to accept granted scope and authorize the application to use that scope.

My question is whether it is possible to do point 3 and 4 programmatically via my backend similarly to point 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the way you are using the keycloak is wrong. using Keycloak APIs directly in the frontend for login and registration functionalities is not the best practice. Instead, Keycloak provides a feature called "themes" that allows customization of the login pages and registration forms without directly interacting with Keycloak APIs.

Using Keycloak's APIs directly in the frontend can indeed limit access to certain functionalities and features offered by Keycloak like

1. Identity Providers Integration
2. Token and Session Management
3. Access to Keycloak Features and MFA
4. Security and Best Practices

You must consider using keycloak-themes feature rather than your app considering authentication as separate entity.

So to answer your quention

I know some how you managed to get 1. Login and 2. Registration get working in hackish way. So if you want to continue the same you have few options

**Option 1 : Try keycloak themes only for update-password.ftl page :**

You can start to learn about themes from this.
Study about themes and implement `update-password.ftl` with your frontend code and implement as look alike to your page. so when user is redirect from the email from the email link he will see the page that is implemented by you but not from your frontend repository instead the UI is from keycloak but looks like what you intended.

**Option 2 : Implement your own password reset system in your app**

In backend create a setup which manages the tokens. Send email link with that token to user email via backend (Not keycloak). This link will redirect to your page
example : [https://your-domain.com/reset-password-here/{backend_token}](https://your-domain.com/reset-password-here/%7Bbackend_token%7D)

When user is redirect to `https://your-domain.com/reset-password-here/{backend_token}`  show him a page to reset the password
Send a request to backend with the `new password` and the `backend_token`
In backend verify user by this `backend_token`.
If he is the expected user then do this

```
user_json = {
    "credentials": [
        {
            "type": "password",
            "temporary": False,
            "value": new_password,
        }
    ]
}

params_path = {"realm-name": self.realm_name, "id": user_id}
data_raw = self.raw_put(
    *emphasized text*"admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/{id}".format(**params_path), data=json.dumps(user_json)
)
```

So the above code would update the keycloak user from your UI.

Again this is not the ideal way of using keycloak. You should consider using themes for the best use of keycloak